# confusion about c++ reference in class

Tags: c++

The following code is correct

```
    string s1="abc";
    string s2="bcd";
    string &rs1=s1;
    string &rs2=s2;
    rs1=rs2;
    cout<<rs1<<"----"<<rs2<<endl;
```

And thefollowing code will compile error:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(string& a):ma(a) { }

    string& ma;
};

string s1="abc";
string s2="bcd";
A oa(s1);
A ob(s2);
oa=ob;
cout<<oa.ma<<"----"<<ob.ma<<endl;
```

All above is `string&` type assignment, why put them into class will cause a compile error?
(gcc version 4.7.1 )

error info is

```
non-static reference member 'std::string& A::ma', can't use default assignment operator
```

Comment: I believe it is because the string passed into ctor (string a) by value, which is a temporary object that is not allowed to initialize the string ref?

Comment: I change that, but it still has error

Comment: @zhenyuyang Please post the *exact* text of the error as an addition to your question; **not** here in a comment.

Comment: `oa.ma = ob.ma` would have the same effect as the first example. Assigning the whole class doesn't work, because the default assignment operator isn't generated when the class contains references or `const` members.

Comment: @BoPersson Exactly, that should be the error he's still getting. At least thats the one clang will throw at me without providing an assignment operator explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a member reference to a local temp variable. the parameter in your constructor is a temp). This is causing a "dangling reference", which is not good.

Change the param to a reference, or change your member to a non-reference. For your purposes you'll likely want:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(string& a):ma(a) { }

    A& operator =(const A& other) 
    { 
        ma = other.ma; 
        return *this; 
    }

    string& ma;
};
```

But you should know, the default copy constructor of your class is probably not going to do what you think it will.

**UPDATE**

Specific area of the standard dealing with why the default copy-assignment operator is deleted when the class has a reference member:

> C++11 § 12.8,p23
>
> A defaulted copy/move assignment operator for class X is defined as deleted if X has:
>   - a variant member with a non-trivial corresponding assignment operator and X is a union-like class, or
>
> - a non-static data member of const non-class type (or array thereof), or
> - **a non-static data member of reference type**, or
> - a non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as applied to M’s corresponding assignment operator, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted assignment operator, or
> - a direct or virtual base class B that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution (13.3), as applied to B’s corresponding assignment operator, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted assignment operator, or
> - for the move assignment operator, a non-static data member or direct base class with a type that does not have a move assignment operator and is not trivially copyable, or any direct or indirect virtual base class.

Comment: @zhenyuyang I updated it to includes the assignment override, but as I said, you may not like the result. (which will be `bcd----bcd` by the way)

Comment: thanks! But why the default assignment operator isn't generated when the class contains **references**?

Comment: @zhenyuyang I'll point to the provision in the standard where the conditions for deleting the default assignment operator are warranted.  I'll need a minute, but ultimately it is because the provided assignment operator is only supposed to modify the *object*, and with a member reference type, that cannot happen. references are forever fixed (unless dangling) once they are established.